# Switch in "main.cpp" is skipping cases with function from "stack.cpp"

Tags: c++, switch-statement, stack

I have 3 files: one with stack define by class in `stack.h`, second with stack's functions in `stack.cpp`, and last one is `main.cpp`. In `main()`, I have a `switch` for an interactive menu:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"

int main() {
    stack s; //for calling functions from stack.cpp
    char choise;
menu: 
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "a => create stack\n" << "b => read data to stack\n" << "c => show data in stack\n" << std::endl; //so it looks like that somehow

    switch(choise) {

        case 'a':
            s.stack(); // function in stack.cpp 
            std::cout << "Stack was created" << std::endl;
            goto menu;

        case 'b':
            s.getdata(); //function in stack.cpp
            goto menu;

        case 'c':
            s.display(); 
            goto menu;
    }
    // and another...
```

The problem is when I'm calling, for example, `'b'`, the program is like skipping it and doesn't call the function from `stack.cpp`. So I can't write or make any other case.

Comment: Maybe I've gone code-blind, but where do you read the `choise` variable? Are you missing a `std::cin >> choise;` line?

Comment: @Adrian Mole  I have it. Just forget to put here

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are missing "break;" in end of each case block?

Try with

```
do
{
   system("cls");
   std::cout << "a => create stack\n" << "b => read data to 
   stack\n" << "c => show data in stack\n" << std::endl; //so it 
   lookss like that somehow
   std::cin >> choise //As Adrian said

    switch(choise) {

        case 'a':
             s.stack(); // function in stack.cpp 
             std::cout << "Stack was created" << std::endl;
             break;

       case 'b':
            s.getdata(); //function in stack.cpp
            break;

       case 'c':
           s.display(); 
           break;
     }
// and another...
}while(1);
```

Comment: I already tried this way, with break. I also tried with if else statement, but it still skipping cases

Comment: @Assaraid maybe your input is not what you expect. Maybe your bug is in `getdata()`